# What is the difference between MEDIA_BUS_FMT_ and DRM_COLOR_FORMAT_?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, drm

I have to configure the input and output bus formats in the drm bridge driver. I am trying to understand the difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Kernel Org Docs - Kernel Mode Setting (KMS)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/gpu/drm-kms.html)

> **`format`**
>
> format used on this bus (one of the `MEDIA_BUS_FMT_*` format)
>
> This field should not be directly modified by drivers
> (`drm_atomic_bridge_chain_select_bus_fmts()` takes care of the bus
> format negotiation).

and

> **`color_formats`**
>
> HDMI Color formats, selects between RGB and YCrCb modes. Used
> `DRM_COLOR_FORMAT_` defines, which are *not* the same ones as used to
> describe the pixel format in framebuffers, and also don’t match the
> formats in `bus_formats` which are shared with v4l.

it seems to be different data structures at a frist glance. Further information might be found under [Media Bus Formats](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.12/media/uapi/v4l/subdev-formats.html).

Comment: They are from different frameworks. Media subsystem is about Video-for-Linux (in most cases it’s about **capturing**), while DRM is about **rendering**.

Comment: @0andriy, thanks, your answer makes it more clear. Maybe you could file a full answer since it would provide more value.

Comment: Yours is good, just needs this small clarification to be added.